# has_excerpt yields true but no post_excerpt when retrieved

Tags: attachments, excerpt

```
echo has_excerpt($att); //Results in True
echo $att->post_excerpt; // results in empty.
echo $att; // results "782" which is the ID of the attached image.
```

If I use `get_post_meta( $att , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)` I get the alternate text but I can't seem to retrieve the caption via `$att->post_excerpt;`.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code you're using to get `$att`?  Are you trying to get an attachment's caption?

Comment: Wait, I might see the problem.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$att` is a numeric post ID, then try this:

```
$attachment = get_post( $att );
echo( $attachment->post_excerpt );
```

[`has_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_excerpt) takes a post ID, but the post ID isn't an object.  You have to get the attachment using [`get_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post), then get the excerpt from there.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.